Trying to understand the nuances of this sentence

The character is describing himself with, I guess, a "sales pitch" on what is attractive about himself.
What I'm stumbling on is:

How to take 甘さも渋さも in the context of physical appearance?  Is he saying he doesn't look too soft but also doesn't look too grim?

How to take 看板店員 here? My take would be a male version of 看板娘  and not a literal someone who holds a sign?



The phrase 兼ね備える can be looked up in Jisho. The meaning follows directly from the parts: more literally, "concurrently furnished with". Since that's preceded by two qualities marked with も the meaning is pretty clear. To express an idea like "not too ..." would involve some form of negation.


It's not accurate to translate it as "not too A and not too B". AもBも兼ね備える means he has the best of both worlds. 甘さ means sweetness/gentleness while 渋さ means mature/rugged gravitas.
Yes, it's a male version of 看板娘. It wouldn't be too much to say 看板 is almost a prefix. See also: What does 看板親父 mean?

